# retrieve image from sqlite and add to listbox tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, blob

Im trying to get a blob image from my db and insert it to listbox but i cant.
any ways to do it?

My entire code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, Tk, Label, filedialog, font
from blobdb import Database
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage
import re
import sqlite3

def fetch_contact ():
    listBox.delete (0, END)

    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('store.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    print("Connected to SQLite")
    sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * from contacts"""
    cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in records:
        listBox.insert (END, (row[1], row[2]))


def convertToBinaryData(filename):
    # Convert digital data to binary format
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        blobData = file.read()
    return blobData


def insertBLOB(id, name, last_name, photo, phone_num, email, home_address):
    print(id, name, last_name, photo, phone_num, email)
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('store.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Connected to SQLite")
        sqlite_insert_blob_query = """ INSERT INTO contacts (id, name, last_name, photo, phone_num, email, home_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

        empPhoto = convertToBinaryData(photo)
        # Convert data into tuple format
        data_tuple = (id, name, last_name, empPhoto,
                      phone_num, email, home_address)
        cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        listBox.delete (0, END)
        fetch_contact()

        print("Image and file inserted successfully as a BLOB into a table")
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert blob data into sqlite table", error)
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("the sqlite connection is closed")


def clear_contacts():
    global photo, image_entry, name_id, image, show_image, image_label
    photo = 'no_image.jpg'
    image_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=photo)
    name_id = ''
    name_entry.delete(0, END)

    lastname_entry.delete(0, END)

    phone_entry.delete(0, END)

    email_entry.delete(0, END)

    address_entry.delete(0, END)


def send_data():
    global photo, image_entry
    regex_email = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
    regex_names = '^[a-zA-Zا-ی]'
    regex_phone = '^[0-9]'

    def check_email(email):
        if (re.search(regex_email, email)):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def check_names(name):
        if (re.search(regex_names, name)):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def check_phone(phone):
        if (re.search(regex_phone, phone)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if name_value.get() == '' or lastname_value.get() == '' or phone_value.get() == '' or email_value.get() == '' or address_value.get() == '':
        messagebox.showerror("Required Fields", "Please include all fields")
        return
    if not check_names(name_value.get()):
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Error", "Please Write Your Firstname Corectly(Just a-z A-Z)")
        return
    if not check_names(lastname_value.get()):
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Error", "Please Write Your Lastname Corectly(Just a-z A-Z)")
        return
    if not check_phone(phone_value.get()):
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Error", "Please Write Your Phone Number Corectly(Just 0-9)")
        return
    if not check_email(email_value.get()):
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "This Email Is Not A Valid Email")
        return
    if photo == '':
        photo = 'no_image.jpg'
        image_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=photo)

    name_id = id(name_value.get())

    insertBLOB(name_id, name_value.get(), lastname_value.get(), photo, phone_value.get(), email_value.get(), address_value.get())

def open_image ():
    global photo, image_entry, image, show_image, image_label
    photo = filedialog.askopenfilename (initialdir="/", title='Select A File', filetypes = (('png files', '*.png'), ('jpg files', '*.jpg')))
    image_entry = Entry (app, textvariable=photo)
    image = photo[:]
    show_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open (image).resize ((80, 80), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    image_label = Label (app, text='', image=show_image)
    image_label.grid (row = 0, column = 1)


app = Tk()
app.title('Contact List')
app.geometry('400x600')
app.configure(background='RoyalBlue4')
icon_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Alora_icon.ico').resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS))
app.iconbitmap(icon_image)

regex_email = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
regex_names = '^[a-zA-Zا-ی]'
regex_phone = '^[0-9]'

# list box
sf= font.Font (family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold')
listBox = Listbox (app, height = 6, width = 15, font = sf)
listBox.place (x = 50, y = 280)

# Scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar (app)
scrollbar.place (x = 378, y = 280)

# set scrollbar to list
listBox.configure (yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure (command = listBox.yview)

fetch_contact()

# name input
name_value = StringVar ()
name = Label (app, text="FIRST NAME")
name.grid (row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
name_entry = Entry (app, textvariable=name_value)
name_entry.grid (row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx = 4, pady = 2)

# last name input
lastname_value = StringVar ()
lastname = Label (app, text="LAST NAME")
lastname.grid (row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
lastname_entry = Entry (app, textvariable=lastname_value)
lastname_entry.grid (row=2, column=1, sticky=W, padx = 4, pady = 2)

# Image
photo = 'no_image.jpg'
image_entry = Entry (app, textvariable=photo)
image = photo[:]
show_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open (image).resize ((80, 80), Image.ANTIALIAS))
image_label = Label (app, text='', image=show_image)
image_label.grid (row = 0, column = 1, padx = 4, pady = 2)

# phone input
phone_value = StringVar ()
phone = Label (app, text="PHONE")
phone.grid (row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
phone_entry = Entry (app, textvariable=phone_value)
phone_entry.grid (row=3, column=1, sticky=W, padx = 4, pady = 2)

# Email input
email_value = StringVar ()
email = Label (app, text="EMAIL")
email.grid (row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
email_entry = Entry (app, textvariable=email_value)
email_entry.grid (row=4, column=1, sticky=W, padx = 4, pady = 2)

# home address input
address_value = StringVar ()
address = Label (app, text="HOME ADDRESS")
address.grid (row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
address_entry = Entry (app, textvariable=address_value)
address_entry.grid (row=5, column=1, sticky=W, padx = 4, pady = 2)

name_id = id (name_value.get())

 
# menubar = Menu (app)
# filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
# filemenu.add_command(label="Add Contact", command= print())
# menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
# app.config(menu=menubar)

add_btn = Button (app, text='ADD CONTACTS', width=12, command=lambda: send_data ())
add_btn.grid (row=7, column=1)

add_photo_btn = Button (app, text='ADD PHOTO', width=12, command=lambda: open_image ())
add_photo_btn.grid (row=0, column=0)

# Start program
app.mainloop ()
```

Comment: You cannot insert image into a `Listbox`.  But you can insert image into `Text` using `Text.image_create()`.

Comment: so after that can i insert this to my list box?

Comment: No, only string can be inserted into `Listbox`.

Comment: so how can i merge my listbox rows to images and show the images?

Comment: you would need to create a scrollable frame, and put images in this frame so they can be scrolled. see https://blog.tecladocode.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/

Comment: Use `Text` instead of `Listbox` to show the image and the text together.

Comment: i cant find anything about Text whats that?

Comment: See the document for [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) widget.

Comment: I read the document and i found that its doesnt related to me becuase i need to have an list of names with their images that when i click on any name it retrieve the name full info and show it.so in  text widget i dont have this option.any other ways?